# Prove $(-a)^{-1} = -a^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification, real-numbers

This is my proof for part (17) of Lemma 2.3.2 in Bloch's Real Analysis. I'd like if someone verifies that I did not miss or skip a step, did anything unjustified, or anything of this sort. I will refer to parts of the [lemma](https://ibb.co/1KgbZ7V) by their number. We start by using the fact that $(-1)^2 = 1$, using inverses law, associative law, and the definition of $a^2$ as described below we reach the conclusion that $(-1)^{-1} = -1$.

(17) First of all, $(-1)^{-1} \neq 0$, because if so then $-1 = ((-1)^{(-1)})^{(-1)}$ will not exist. Which we know is false. Now, we prove that $(-1)^{-1} = -1$.
\begin{align*}
    &(-1)^2 = 1 &&\textbf{(14)} \\ 
    &(-1)^2 \cdot (-1)^{-1} = 1 \cdot (-1)^{-1}& &\textbf{Multiply by $(-1)^{-1}$} \\ 
    &(-1)\cdot((-1)\cdot (-1)^{-1}) = (-1)^{-1} &&\textbf{RHS: Definition of $a^2$, LHS: $1a = a$} \\ 
    &(-1)\cdot 1 = (-1)^{-1} &&\textbf{$aa^{-1} = 1$} \\
    &-1 = (-1)^{-1} &&\textbf{$a1=a$}
\end{align*}
After that we prove that $(-a)^{-1} = -a^{-1}$.
\begin{align*}
    &(-a)^{-1} = ((-1)a)^{-1} &&\textbf{(11)} \\
    &(-1)^{-1}a^{-1} &&\textbf{(10)} \\ 
    &(-1)a^{-1} &&\textbf{Above} \\ 
    &-a^{-1} &&\textbf{(11)}
\end{align*}

Comment: Compare your prove with [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402623/use-the-axioms-for-the-field-of-real-number-to-prove-1-a-1-a).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't see how comparing a proof (in this case, one that doesn't even bother mentioning the axioms it's based on) helpful in verifying that I wrote a correct and formal proof that does not miss steps or needs further justification. I wanted someone to check the details of the proof and its technicalities.

Comment: Lhf writes: "here is an argument". Do you see that it is comparable with yours? For example, $1/(-1)=-1$? What is the difference? I think that he says exactly what he is using.

Comment: Yes, there are similarities, and there's an outline of proof there. That does not help me verify that I followed the outline correctly.

Comment: Oh, it helps very much. It is exactly what is needed. You can fill in the details, I am sure.

Comment: I came here to ask someone to kindly check that I filled in the details correctly.

Comment: Yes, I understand. On the other hand, what exactly is unclear to you? By comparing you will see whether you are correct or not. And this, finding out yourself, is so much more worth than just "believing" someone here. You will learn much more, by doing this yourself. And I am sure you can. Perhaps this is the "kind" help you truly need.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  I'll give an example. Prove if $c \neq 0$ and $ac = bc$ then $a = b$. This is highly trivial you just multiply by $c^{-1}$ and get $a = b$. However, for a beginner in real analysis like me, I should justify all steps. So the previous one-liner is not enough, it basically ignores the fact that multiplying three numbers is not defined it and hence it must be $(ac)c^{-1} = a(cc^{-1}) = a1 = a$. It is easy to miss such details, and so such details must be checked for a beginner like me, or else I am not doing anything rigorously as it should be done.

Comment: So you see. You can fill in the details yourself! What about $1/(ab)=(1/a)\cdot (1/b)$?

Comment: No, I missed those details at first and someone told me. And there's no point in this discussion, it only adds more comments that are not really related to the question.

Comment: $a^{-1}b^{-1} = (ab)^{-1}$ was proved before in the text.